# Soyuz reentry acceleration profile with timing

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, soyuz-spacecraft

I am looking for reentry Soyuz acceleration profile with timing. I was able to find graphs for ascent, but failed to find anything related with descent. The only thing I've got is Andreas Mogensen Human Centrifuge test run in Star City.

I am interested in both nominal reentry and ballistic. Preferably a scientific publication with g-load analysis, but I'll take anything :)

- https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-typical-acceleration-profile-experienced-by-an-astronaut-look-like/answer/C-Stuart-Hardwick
- https://www.quora.com/How-many-g-forces-do-astronauts-experience-on-the-Soyuz-rocket#mVtDV

[image: Andreas Mogensen centrifuge training]

Comment: Great question! The Soyuz Crew Ops Manual just has the same drawing you see everywhere which gives 4-5 g's for normal, 8-9 g's for ballistic, but no detailed time trace.